# java : Unknown return ('L') type for boolean value

Tags: java

In this method the symbol value can be anything Stock Symbol like (For example GOOG , C , DAC-----etc)

```
private boolean isC(String symbol) {
    char code = symbol.charAt(symbol.length() - 2);
    return code <= 'L';
}
```

Could anybody please let me know what does this return type mean exactly ??

I am confused because i was thinking of a return type to be either `true` or `false`, but could anybody please let me know what does this  `'L'` mean exactly ??

Thanks in advance .

Comment: The return value is the value of the boolean expression `code <= 'L'`. Java chars are comparable.

Comment: 'L' is represented also as an integer value (http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). 'L' is equal to 0x4C. method isC returns result of comaprision

Answer (score 3):

returns true if the ascii code of the character in the variable 'code' is less than or equal to the ascii code for L.

false otherwise

Comment: Thank yo very much all ,  my bad i was seeing at from 30 feet high .

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a condition stated after the return keyword the condition is getting evaluated first and the result of the evaluation is then getting returned.

And because a condition can only be true or false the return type of this method is boolean.

Here when you apply the <= operator with the type char you are comparing the numerical ASCII representation of a char.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the [ascii code](http://www.asciitable.com/) of some of the characters here. `code <= 'L'` is a comparison between the ascii code of the value of `code` and `'L'`